# Embarcadero C++ Builder XE2 build errors

Tags: c++builder-xe2

I am using (for now) a trial version of Embarcadero C++ Builder XE2 Architect. I am working through migrating our current code from Borland C++ Builder 6.

There a some type libraries that I have been importing and installing into a package. So far the ones I have run into have imported just fine. However, I needed to import the OLE Automation 2.0 library. Upon doing this, I receive several errors, the first of which is mentioned in the title of this post.

The other libraries I have imported so far are: Crystal Reports ActiveX Designer Run Time Library 11.0 (craxdrt.dll) and Microsoft Jet and Replication Objects 2.6 Library (msjro.dll).

The following shows where the IDE says the problems are (file stdole_TLB.h):

```
typedef Stdole_tlb::IFontDisp IFontDisp;
typedef Stdole_tlb::IFontDisp *IFontDispPtr;
typedef Stdole_tlb::IPictureDisp IPictureDisp;
typedef Stdole_tlb::IPictureDisp *IPictureDispPtr;
```

The full parser context messages for those just show:

```
stdole_TLB.cpp(28): #include ..\9.0\Imports\stdole_TLB.h
stdole_TLB.h(56): namespace Stdole_tlb
```

I also receive another error message:

```
[BCC32 Error] stdole_TLB.h(254): E2029 'TDispWrapper<IDispatch>' must be a previously defined class or struct
  Full parser context
    stdole_TLB.cpp(28): #include ..\9.0\Imports\stdole_TLB.h
    stdole_TLB.h(56): namespace Stdole_tlb
    stdole_TLB.h(253): class IUnknown
```

That last one generates a lot of error messages so I think if that could be knocked out, most of the errors will go away.

Any help is much appreciated!